# Looping and then running macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of values in a sheet named "Codes"

I have another sheet "Input" that contains a cell B1 where I have to input one of the values from the column in "Codes"

Then I have to run a macro with that value in "Input" B1. I have the whole column of values to run the macro. How can I create a loop to do so?

Comment: It sounds like the right construct for your situation is a `For` loop. Here's a great [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx) that details many examples of `For` loops -- I suggest trying one of those and then posting your attempted code if you are still having issues

Comment: Some really nice folks below have decided to write code for you... Not really the purpose of Stack Overflow but I guess you get lucky sometimes...

Comment: Actually I got it figured out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you validating the input? If so there is an automated way to this in Excel using data validation. Look in the `Data` tab for the `Data Validation` dialog box, and pick `Allow: List` with `Source: =Codes!B2:B100` for example.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: scr]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood what you're asking for, you need to loop through your Codes range and feed them into another macro that will put those codes in 'Input'!B1.  You can do so with code that looks like this:

```
Sub LoopMacro()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCodes As Range
    Dim CodeCell As Range

    'Specify the range of cells that contain the codes
    'This example assumes they are in worksheet named 'Codes' and in column A starting at A1
    Set ws = Sheets("Codes")
    Set rngCodes = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    'Then loop through each cell that contains the code and call your macro where you need to provide the input
    For Each CodeCell In rngCodes.Cells
        Call AcceptsInput(CodeCell.Value)
    Next CodeCell

End Sub
```

And here is the code for the `AcceptsInput` macro:

```
Sub AcceptsInput(ByVal strCode As String)

    'This macro accepts the input
    'From here you can do what you want with it
    'Using your stated goal, you would put the code in worksheet named 'Input' in cell B1
    Sheets("Input").Range("B1").Value = strCode

    'Additional code goes here

End Sub
```